# Why is cycles render black and white?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, color

I have a blender project I am working on. I just started, and I made a sphere. If I switch from solid mode to rendered preview mode, I get this:
[image]

But, when I press f12 to render, I get this:
[image]

Why? Why is this happening? Please help

Here is my blend file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6wato3bfp187rs/blender.blend?dl=1

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are in [local view](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html#view-global-local). The plane appears to not be integrated in the render layers. Perhaps you have added it in local view (it looks like a bug)?

Simply press the <kbd>NumpadDivision</kbd> key (<kbd>÷</kbd>) to exit *local view*.